# Add npm pckage in odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, npm-install, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to use a npm package in odoo so that I can use that in odoo widget. I have seen that odoo web add on somehow uses underscore js and query. But I am not able to use npm package in odoo.

I have tried to load it by creating package.json file inside the addon folder but it is not working. Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern is to put all dependencies directly copied in the `static/src/lib/` folder of the addon, and enable them in a `templates/assets.xml` file. Using npm would be theoretically nice, but it is probably going to give you more problems than benefits, and you will need to do all the plumbing yourself manually. Check https://github.com/OCA/web/issues/842 for more background on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below:

## Odoo Web Dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install -y npm

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css

sudo apt-get install node-less

sudo python3 -m pip install libsass
```